# Save and load dictionaries to HDFS with Python

Tags: python, pyspark, hdfs

I need to **save** a nested dictionary to HDFS and **load** it again. I am aware that I cannot save JSON-like objects on HDFS, but solutions like [this one](https://gist.github.com/connerxyz/3f44ecb78ef6122f94f77034f17d798a) solve this by converting the dictionary to a dataframe. How do I then load this dictionary again, when it is stored as a dataframe?

Desired API:

```
my_dict = # ...

# Save it
save_dict_to_HDFS(dict_, path)

# Load it
my_dict_loaded = load_dict_from_HDFS(path)

# Check that it is unchanged
assert(my_dict == my_dict_loaded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply load the dataframe, collect the 0th row and call the `.asDict` method on the row.

```
def save_dict_to_HDFS(dict_, path):
    """Store dictionary on HDFS

    Parameter:
    ----------
    dict_ : dict
        Dictionary to store on HDFS.
    path : str
    """
    sc.parallelize([dict_]).toDF().write.mode('overwrite').save(path)
    return output_table_name

def load_dict_from_HDFS(path):
    """Load dictionary from HDFS
    
    Input
    -----
        path : str
    Return
    ------
        dict
    """
    return spark.read.load(path).collect()[0].asDict()
```

Then your code example will run.